# Loop to calculate coordinates between start and end angle

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset with cell tower information, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh1ZP.png). The lat and lon fields are the location of the tower.

[image]

My objective is to discover the area these towers cover by calculating every coordinate from the start_angle to the end_angle, increasing the angle by 1 each time you do the calculation.
I know the formula to achieve the coordinate given the angle and radius. My problem is that  can't create a loop that calculates each coordinate for each id.

Comment: Isn't area for each tower equal to `Pi * radius^2 * abs(end_angle - start_angle) / 360`? Do you just need a code to sum up this expression for all towers?

Comment: My problem is that I need every coordinate of the area from the start angle to the end angle. Imagine the line that creates the area the cell covers. I need the coordinate of each point from the start angle + 1 until it reaches the end angle

Comment: Do you mean you need to go through coordinates of all points inside of [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) with certain small step? Then you may do nested loops, one by angle, one by radius.

Comment: When you say "you have a dataset", then you mean a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Arty https://imgur.com/a/xw4rOMS - I hope with this image you can better understand my problem. Imagining the start angle is 0 and the end angle is 90, I need to know the coordinates of each point at 0 degrees, 1 degrees, etc, until it reaches the end angle. I just cant understand how to create a loop that does the same calcultion for each angle

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for computing area if this is what you needed. For each tower I'm computing area as `Pi * radius^2 * abs(end_angle - start_angle) / 360`. This is just a simple formula for [area of circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector#Area).

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, math

a = pd.read_csv('test.csv').values
print(np.sum(a[:, 3] * a[:, 3] * ((a[:, 5] - a[:, 4]) % 360.)) * math.pi / 360.)
```

If you needed to iterate through all points within [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) then I wrote next code.

It does steps through each 1 degree of angle and 1 meter of radius. And converts coordinates of points of circular sector expressed in meters to lat/lon coordinates expressed in degrees, for that I use [this formulas](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) in `Dist()` function to compute lat/lon distance compression ratio, to correct distance for lon (the more we're close to poles the more lon distance is smaller than lat, the closer we're to equator the more lon distance is closer to lat and equal on equator), lat distance doesn't need correction (it is everywhere `111km` for each 1 degree of lat).

My stepping-iteration is not uniform, meaning that I do iterate everywhere 1 degree of angle and 1 meter of radius, meaning if you have tower radius 50 and angle of 80 degrees then you'll have exactly 50 * 80 = 4000 points iterated. If you need area-wise uniform iteration, tell me, I'll change code, or you can do it yourself, you just need to iterate through 1 meter of radius in outer loop and inner loop should iterate through angles, but more angle steps should be at larger radiuses and fewer at smaller radiuses, then you'll have uniform filling. You have to tell what you need.

Next code needs installing 3 packages using `python -m pip install pandas numpy tqdm`. `tqdm` is just progress bar implementation.

If you need to process a lot of data and pure python code is too slow, I can extend my solution for using `numpy` arrays which will much faster.

First simplified slow older version of code with non-uniform stepping can be [found and run here online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63996817#main.py).

**Update!** I've implemented second version, which is more advanced, runs much faster (uses `numpy` for heavy parts) and also creates grids over sectors with uniform stepping (step size in meters is controlled by `mdist` value in the beginning of script). Main function `GenPoints()` is generator which iteratively parses CSV and yields (returns) points for grid of each tower's sector as (lon, lat) numpy array, also attaching parsed dataframe for those towers. Also implemented drawing results into image files. Down are two results of drawing. As you can see second result is ellipsoid, that's due to this tower being at 60 degrees latitude where objects are quite stretched horizontally in [Mercator Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

[image: test0.png]

and

[image: test1.png]

Next is version 2 code. You can also [run next code online here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63996817ver2#main.py):

Test file:

```
id,lat,lon,radius,start_angle,end_angle
1,2.1,3.7,30.5,50.3,100.1
2,60.0,5.8,10.6,80.4,30.2
```

Code:

```
import math, sys, os
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, tqdm

ifname = 'test.csv'
mdist = 1. # Minimal distance in meters between points in grid covering tower's sector
ofname = 'test{i}.png' # Outpu file names for drawing

def GenPoints():
    pi = math.pi
    asteps = 360 * 2 # Number of steps along full circle, 360 * 2 corresponds to precision of 0.5 degree.
    lat_deg2m = 111000
    latlon_ratio_deg_steps = 100
    fdtype = np.float64
    
    def LonLatDist(p1, p2):
        # Exact distance between two points on Earth, points given by (lon, lat) tuple.
        # See https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
        
        lon1, lat1 = p1[:2]
        lon2, lat2 = p2[:2]
        
        R = 6371000 # metres
        # phi, lam in radians
        phi1 = lat1 * pi / 180
        phi2 = lat2 * pi / 180
        dphi = (lat2 - lat1) * pi / 180
        dlam = (lon2 - lon1) * pi / 180

        a = abs(math.sin(dphi / 2)) ** 2 + math.cos(phi1) * math.cos(phi2) * abs(math.sin(dlam / 2)) ** 2
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
        d = R * c # in metres
        return d

    def frange(start, stop, step):
        x = start
        while x < stop:
            yield x
            x += step
            
    class dict2obj(object):
        def __init__(self, dict_):
            self.__dict__.update(dict_)
            
    def multi_arange(a):
        steps = a[:,2]
        lens = ((a[:,1]-a[:,0]) + steps-1)//steps
        b = np.repeat(steps, lens)
        ends = (lens-1)*steps + a[:,0]
        b[0] = a[0,0]
        b[lens[:-1].cumsum()] = a[1:,0] - ends[:-1]
        return b.cumsum()

    def GetPts(*, re, ab, ae, dat = {'pts': np.zeros([0, 2], dtype = fdtype), 'idx': np.zeros([0, 2 * asteps + 1], dtype = np.int64)}):
        while (dat['idx'].shape[0] - 1) * mdist < re:
            r = dat['idx'].shape[0] * mdist
            if dat['idx'].shape[0] > 0:
                a = 2 * math.asin(mdist / (2 * r)) # r*2*sin(a/2) = mdist
                n = math.floor(2 * pi / a)
            else:
                n = 1
            as_ = np.linspace(0., 4 * pi, 2 * n, endpoint = False)
            idx = np.concatenate((
                np.searchsorted(as_, np.linspace(0., 4 * pi, 2 * asteps, endpoint = False), side = 'right'),
                np.array([2 * n], dtype = np.int64),
            ))
            xs = r * np.cos(as_)
            ys = r * np.sin(as_)
            
            dat['idx'] = np.concatenate((dat['idx'], idx[None, :] + dat['pts'].shape[0]))
            dat['pts'] = np.concatenate((dat['pts'], np.vstack((xs, ys)).transpose()))
            assert dat['idx'][-1, -1] == dat['pts'].shape[0]
        assert 0. <= ab <= ae <= 4 * pi, (ab, ae)
        ire = round(float(re / mdist))
        iab, iae = [round(float(a / (2 * pi / asteps))) for a in [ab, ae]]
        pb, pe = [dat['idx'][:ire + 1, ia] for ia in [iab, iae + 1]]
        #return np.concatenate([dat['pts'][b : e, :] for b, e in zip(np.nditer(pb), np.nditer(pe))])
        return dat['pts'][multi_arange(np.vstack((pb, pe, np.ones_like(pb))).T), :]
        
    def Deg2Rad(a):
        return a * pi / 180.
            
    def GetLLRatio(*, lat, dat = {'tab': None}):
        if dat['tab'] is None:
            dat['tab'] = np.array([
                LonLatDist((-shift, clat), (shift, clat)) / LonLatDist((0., clat - shift), (0., clat + shift))
                for ilat in range(0, 90 * latlon_ratio_deg_steps) for shift, clat in [(0.00001, ilat / latlon_ratio_deg_steps)]
            ], dtype = fdtype)
        assert -90. <= lat <= 90., lat
        return dat['tab'][min(90 * latlon_ratio_deg_steps - 1, round(float(abs(lat) * latlon_ratio_deg_steps)))]
    
    fsize = os.path.getsize(ifname)
    area = 0.
    with open(ifname, 'rb', buffering = 1 << 16) as fin, tqdm.tqdm(total = fsize, ascii = True, unit = 'B') as prctr:
        for idf, df in enumerate(pd.read_csv(fin, iterator = True, chunksize = 1 << 4)):
            if idf == 0:
                # id,lat,lon,radius,start_angle,end_angle
                cols = dict2obj({e : ie for ie, e in enumerate(df.columns.values.tolist())})
                
            istart = df.index[0]
                
            a = df.values.astype(np.float64)
            
            area += np.sum(a[:, cols.radius] * a[:, cols.radius] * ((a[:, cols.end_angle] - a[:, cols.start_angle]) % 360.)) * pi / 360.
            
            for i in range(a.shape[0]):
                row = a[i, :]
                pts = GetPts(
                    re = row[cols.radius],
                    ab = Deg2Rad(row[cols.start_angle]),
                    ae = Deg2Rad(row[cols.end_angle] + (0., 360.)[int(row[cols.start_angle] >= row[cols.end_angle])]),
                )
                lats = pts[:, 1] / lat_deg2m + row[cols.lat]
                lons = pts[:, 0] / (lat_deg2m * GetLLRatio(lat = row[cols.lat])) + row[cols.lon]
                yield {
                    'idx': istart + i,
                    'data': df.iloc[i : i + 1, :],
                    'points': np.vstack((lons, lats)).transpose(),
                }

            prctr.update(fin.tell() - prctr.n)
        prctr.update(fsize - prctr.n)

def Draw():
    import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageDraw
    
    swidth = 1048
    sradius = 10
    antialias_mult = 1 # Degree of antialiasing, 1 - Not antialiased, 2 - Some antialiasing, 4 - Good antialiasing
    
    for iv, v in enumerate(GenPoints()):
        ps = v['points']
        xmin, xmax = np.amin(ps[:, 0]), np.amax(ps[:, 0])
        ymin, ymax = np.amin(ps[:, 1]), np.amax(ps[:, 1])
        
        sheight = math.ceil(swidth * (ymax - ymin) / (xmax - xmin))
        
        assert antialias_mult in [1, 2, 4, 8], antialias_mult
        width = swidth * antialias_mult
        radius = sradius * antialias_mult
        height = sheight * antialias_mult
        
        img = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
        imgd = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(np.nditer(ps[:, 0]), np.nditer(ps[:, 1]))):
            imgd.ellipse([
                (width - 2 * radius) * (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin),
                (height - 2 * radius) * (ymax - y) / (ymax - ymin),
                (width - 2 * radius) * (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin) + 2 * radius,
                (height - 2 * radius) * (ymax - y) / (ymax - ymin) + 2 * radius,
            ], fill = (round(255 * (1 - i / ps.shape[0] * 0.9)),) * 3, outline = 'black')

        if antialias_mult > 1:
            img = img.resize([swidth, sheight], PIL.Image.LANCZOS)
            
        img.save(ofname.format(i = iv))
        
def TestFast():
    print(len(list(GenPoints())))

Draw()
#TestFast()
```